# convert long to object then to ulong

Tags: c#, casting, implicit-conversion

why C# can't implicitly convert a long var to an object var then to ulong?

```
    long a = 0;
    Object c = a;
    ulong b = (ulong)c; // throw exception here
```

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080945/why-cant-i-pull-a-ushort-from-a-system-object-and-then-cast-it-as-a-uint-c/1080957#1080957

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you box a value type T, you can only unbox it as itself or as a Nullable ( T? ).
Any other cast is invalid.

That's because a cast from object can never be interpreted as a conversion, whereas the is a conversion between long and ulong.

So this is legal:

```
var c = (long) b;
```

This is also legal:

```
var c = (long?) b;
```

But this is not:

```
var c = (ulong) b;
```

To do what you want to, you have to cast twice: the first is only unboxing, and the second is the actual conversion:

```
var c = (ulong)(long) b;
```

For further information, see this [blog post by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx).

Comment: Hah,Thanks for your help. Your link is very useful. It's exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 7):

you can only unbox to the exact same type as was boxed

```
 Object c = a
```

boxes a which is a long

```
 ulong b = (ulong)c;
```

tries to unbox c as a ulong but it is a long and hence fails.

```
 ulong b = (ulong)((long)c);
```

would work since it unboxes c as a long. c being long this will work and you can cast long to ulong

Comment: You can go `ulong b = (ulong)(long) c`, though (overflows and underflows not withstanding).

Comment: @akton correct. I wanted to make the evaluation of the expressions explicit hence the extra set of ()

Answer (score 1):

All the above result in a loss of data if the value is greater than the maximum value of a `long` (9,223,372,036,854,775,807).

`ulong` has a minimum of zero and a maximum of 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.

To convert without this risk use

```
ulong b = Convert.ToUInt64(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple answer: beacuse long and ulong are not the same type. One is a signed long the other is an unsigned long.